# Why does .NET say that subnormal numbers are never powers of 2?

Tags: c#, .net-core, floating-point, double, subnormal-numbers

Since .NET 7 (from 2022), there has been a static [method `double.IsPow2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.ispow2).

Who decided it should never consider subnormal numbers as powers of 2? For example, if I try this code:

```cs
double exp = -1000.0;
while (true)
{
    double pow2 = double.Exp2(exp);
    if (pow2 == 0.0)
    {
        break;
    }
    bool isOk = double.IsPow2(pow2);
    Console.WriteLine($"{exp} {isOk}");
    --exp;
}
```

it produces output like:

```
...
-1020 True
-1021 True
-1022 True
-1023 False
-1024 False
-1025 False
...
```

So a number like `Exp2(-1024.0)` (a.k.a. `Pow(2.0, -1024.0)` or `5.562684646268003E-309`) is not allowed as a power of 2. But it seems it could be useful; for example, the eleven numbers:

> `Exp2(-1024.0)`, `Exp2(-1024.1)`, `Exp2(-1024.2)`, `Exp2(-1024.3)`, ..., `Exp2(-1025.0)`

are all different, but the first one and the last one are "more" powers of 2 than the other nine ones are?

Comment: Either it is a bug in `IsPow2` or the software is running in a mode where subnormal results or operands are flushed to zero, so `IsPow2` is only received zero, not a subnormal value. When you print the result of `Exp2` directly, what does it show?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `if (pow2 == 0.0)` should have prevented the "IsPow2 is only received zero" case.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, but that would require me to read all the code in the question, clearly an undue burden. In any case “A and B” and “Not B” implies “A”, so there is a bug in `IsPow2`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `IsPow2()` simply looks broken, and MS prefers to stay that way than [do it right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_problem#:~:text=Microsoft%20Excel%20has%2C%20since%20its,the%20purpose%20of%20backward%20compatibility.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug [reported here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/88023) and fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/88839/commits/e1b59de919867e58150395c45de3fc5ae436f7be).

Note that the commit shows that some tests were wrong, i.e. it was previously assumed that `IsPow2` should not return true on subnormals.